# Compile Error in Expression

Tags: c#

So I am experiencing a small issue with my current code regarding a BMI calculator. I have searched the other BMI calculator topics here and none of them seemed to help me. Keep in mind that I am very new to ASP.Net and have yet to really master anything! I have been told that JS would make my life easier, but I **MUST** do this in ASP.net.

For the BMI calculator I am using standard measurements of Feet, Inches, and Pounds. There are three text boxes which hold this information. For the calculation portion of my code, I would like the event handler to check to see if ONLY numeric values are entered into the text boxes and then calculate an individuals BMI. The result of the calculation should then appear in the fourth text box titled "Results". The code below is as far as I have gotten.

```
//*************Event Handler for the calculation portion*****************

void calcUS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Heightinfeet = heightus.Text;
    string Heightininches = heightus1.Text;
    string Weight = weightus.Text;

    double number;


    string bmi = resultus.Text;

    bool isHeightinfeet = Double.TryParse(Heightinfeet, out number);
    bool isHeightininches = Double.TryParse(Heightininches, out number);
    bool isWeight = Double.TryParse(Weight, out number);


    if (isHeightinfeet && isHeightininches && isWeight)
    {
        bmi = (Weight / ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches)) * ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches))) * 703);
    }

    else
    {
        Response.Write("Please type a numeric value into each of the text boxes.");
    }
}
//*****************End of calculation Event Handler*******************
```

Everything seems to be working with the exception of the actual computation portion of

```
if (isHeightinfeet && isHeightininches && isWeight)
{
    bmi = (Weight / ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches)) * ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches))) * 703);
}
```

In the formula above, I get the error of "Operator "*" cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' or 'int'" when I hover my mouse over "Heightinfeet" and "Heightininches"

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET or event handling. Simply reading the error message and glancing at the code will show you the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that! But there lies my problem, I do not understand the errors because I am new to this type of code

Comment: What kind of code? C#? Forget about ASP.NET and event handling and just look at the line that the compiler gives you an error on. Look at the type of each variable. Read the error message again.

Comment: The operator `*` does multiplication; you already know that. And then the error tells you that you can't do multiplication on `string`s and `int`s. That's because can't multiply `string`s at all--what would that even mean? Instead, you have to convert the `string` values to `int` values, then multiply the two `int`s.

Comment: I get that now, but I don't know how to do it :/

Answer (score 0):

This is little refactoring I could do

```
int Heightinfeet;
double Heightininches;
double Weight;

if (int.TryParse(heightus.Text, out Heightinfeet) && 
    Double.TryParse(heightus1.Text, out Heightininches) && 
    Double.TryParse(weightus.Text, out Weight))
{
  bmi = (Weight / ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches)) * ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches))) * 703);
}
```

Comment: And how do I go about doing so Simon McKenzie? I am truly clueless! and thank you Sundeep.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can't make "*" operation on `int` which in this case the number "12" and string which in this case `Heightinfeet`

so you should parse the string first into int or double to be used.

`(int.Parse(Heightinfeet) * 12)`  OR it's Double   `(double.Parse(Heightinfeet) * 12)`

Comment: Thank you for the help ebram. That seems to have cleared up some of the issue. But now I am getting "double does not contain definition for parse" when I hover over .parse in the code.

Comment: So now I have 
`{
                            bmi = (Weight / ((double.Parse(Heightinfeet) * 12) + Heightininches)) * ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches))) * 703);
                        }`

and it is saying that there is an invalid argument for double.Parse

Comment: Yes unfortunately :(. I really appreciate the help though

Comment: `{
                            bmi = (Weight / ((double.Parse(Heightinfeet) * 12) + Heightininches)) * ((Heightinfeet * 12) + Heightininches))) * 703);
                        }`
At ((double.Parse(Heightinfeet) * 12) I am getting an invalid argument

Comment: to be clear any string you use should be first parsed into double or int before using it in math operations.